# MySQL Stored Procedure Optimization

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, out-of-memory, query-optimization

I have the following stored procedure in Mysql. My columns has to be dynamic so that I'm converting rows to columns. I have a temporary table to store my data which I needed, then I'm concatenating rows to be column with if statements but I'm getting out of memory error in mysql. Is there any way to optimize my query to work efficiently in mysql workbench (64bit operating system with 4gb Ram)?

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
         PROCEDURE `myWordDistributionsQueryAll`(OUT myOutput text)
 BEGIN
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpWeightTable
           (INDEX(word,topicName) ) ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AS  (

        SELECT wwt.topicName, t.topic_cnt as sumOfWordsInTopic,
               wwt.word, wwt.wordCount,
               (wwt.wordCount / t.topic_cnt) AS wordProbability
         FROM weightallofwordsintopic as wwt JOIN
             (SELECT topicName, sum(wordCount) AS topic_cnt
              FROM weightallofwordsintopic 
              GROUP BY topicName 
            ) t
         ON wwt.topicName = t.topicName
    );

    SET @sql = '';
    SELECT @sql := CONCAT(@sql,if(@sql='','',', '),temp.output)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
          DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
             'SUM(IF(word = ''',
              word,
              ''', wordProbability, 0)) AS ',
              word
            ) as output
        FROM
            tmpWeightTable 
    ) as temp;


    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT topicName, ', @sql, ' FROM tmpWeightTable
          group by topicName order by topicName asc');
    SET myOutput=@sql;           
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE weightallofwordsintopic (
    topicName varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
    word varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    wordCount int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    KEY topicName_index (topicName), 
    KEY word_index (word)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin5
```

Comment: How many rows?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE weightallofwordsintopic`.  Won't `GROUP_CONCAT()` be easier?

Comment: Hello @RickJames thanks for your interest, create table script as follows       
                                                                                                               
   CREATE TABLE `weightallofwordsintopic` (
  `topicName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `word` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wordCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `topicName_index` (`topicName`),
  KEY `word_index` (`word`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin5;    number of rows are too large maybe 500k  but when i convert to row i made it distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the 'derived' table inside the `SELECT @sql` be

```
( SELECT CONCAT(
             SUM(...), ...
             word
         ) AS output
    FROM tmpWeightTable
    GROUP BY word )
```

This will do the grouping, which seemed to be missing before.

But there is probably another problem.  That needs to be inside

```
SELECT @list := GROUP_CONCAT(",", item)
    FROM ( SELECT 
                CONCAT("'", word,":", SUM(wordProbability), "'") AS item
            FROM tmpWeightTable
            GROUP BY word
          ) AS z;
```

Then put the sql together with

```
SELECT @sql := CONCAT('SELECT topicName, ', @list, 
      ' FROM ??  group by topicName order by topicName asc');
```

I'm getting lost...  Please provide sample strings for each stage.

Comment: Hello what you mean with inner query, which one ?

Comment: sum for each topic is different so that i cant sum probability with grouping by word

Comment: Please show sample input and output, with only a small number of topics and words.

Comment: Suppose that i have this record in my table  first col is topicName, second one word and third one is wordcount.. So probability is division of wordCount to sum of words in that topic.                                
 20160610-20160611 T0 başkan 318
20160610-20160611 T0 cenaze 254
20160610-20160611 T0 adam 247
20160610-20160611 T0 türk 188
20160610-20160611 T0 şehit 182
20160610-20160611 T1 üniversite 240
20160610-20160611 T1 okul 150
20160610-20160611 T1 çalış 145
20160610-20160611 T1 final 144
20160610-20160611 T1 sınav 140

Comment: No way am I installing whatever that has in it!

Comment: Try putting the images in some place that does not insist on installing spyware.